# Saving Attachments by Sender address

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to append the sender address to my attachment filenames.

For example, I get an email from johnsmith@fakeemail.com with the attachment somespreadsheet.xls.

I'd like to automatically save that file as somespreadsheet.johnsmith.xls (or any variation of that filename will work).

I receive about 200 of these spreadsheets a day, but they are all named the same, somespreadsheet.xls, and I am looking for a faster/easier way to get them all pulled from my emails while maintaining who sent them to me.

Comment: Do you already have code that saves the files?

Answer (score 0):

The Attachment class from the Outlook object model provides the [SaveAsFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359(v=office.15).aspx) method which allows to specify the filename.

```
Sub SaveAttachment() 
   Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector  
   Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
   Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments  

   Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector 

   If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then  
      If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then  
         Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem  
      Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments  

   'Prompt the user for confirmation  
   Dim strPrompt As String  
   strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."  
   If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then  
      myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _  
      myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName  
   End If  
 Else  
   MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."  
 End If  
End If  
End Sub
```

As you may see the [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862398(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Attachment class is used for specifying the file name. So you may combine it with the Sender* related properties of the MailItem class - see [SenderName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869598(v=office.15).aspx) and [SenderEmailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868262(v=office.15).aspx) properties.